# Split string into an array with regular expression excluding a word

Tags: javascript, regex

There was a question asked today, that piqued my interest (and subsequently was deleted) where the user wanted to split the following string **with a regular expression**

```
'The 1. cat 2. sat 3. on 4. the 5. mat';
```

into this array

```
["cat","sat","on","the","mat"]
```

there were answers with this expression

```
str.match(/[a-z]+/gi);
```

which of course returns

```
["The","cat","sat","on","the","mat"]
```

The nearest I come come to an answer was with

```
str.match(/[^The][a-z]+/gi);
```

which returns

```
[" cat"," sat"," on"," the"," mat"]
```

Unit tested [here](http://www.unittest.it/unittestcase/1SCtYcS/)

Of course this can be done, but how?

Comment: so you are looking forward to remove that spaces before each string in the array?

Comment: I am looking to do it exactly how it was asked, the users answering the question had there own opinion as to what the op was asking. I tried to take it at face value.

Comment: `[^The]` is exactly the same than: `[^heT]`, `[^eTh]`, ...and all possible permutations. `[^The]` doesn't mean "not the word `The`" but "not these letters"

Comment: The op asked to exclude the first The (as I read it)

Answer (score 1):

How about

Javascript

```
var str = 'The 1. cat 2. sat 3. on 4. the 5. mat',
    arr1 = str.match(/[a-z]+/gi),
    arr2 = str.match(/\b[a-z]+/g);

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Output

```
["The", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"] 
["cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Bk9KE/)

Comment: Are you removing the first element of the array?

Comment: Yes, you did not want the first word? Did you? If you do, just remove the `slice`

Comment: Yes, suppose, but I was trying to not to chain and just use a reg ex

Comment: Sorry, you do or do not want the first word in the array?

Comment: Yes, but only with a reg ex as the op asked

Answer (score 0):

```
str.match(/\b(?!The\b)[a-z]+\b/gi)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pattern:

```
str.match(/\b[a-z]+\b(?!\s1\.)/gi)
```

Comment: @NicholasMurray: your test is probably false.

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad! I was using equal instead of deepEqual http://www.unittest.it/unittestcase/M91bM1r/4/